# How do I check tag_ID in wordpress php code?

Tags: php, wordpress

I can check page_id like below in header.php file

```
<?php if (!is_page('792')) { ?>

***** The Header Code is HERE *****

<?php } ?>
```

But if I tried to check tag_ID in same manner it is giving me error

```
<?php if (!tag_ID('121')) { ?>
    
    ***** The Header Code is HERE *****
    
    <?php } ?>
```

ERROR

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function tag_ID()
>
> Basically I want to hide HEADER section so it is working perfect on page but not on tag_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tag_ID()` is not a defined [WordPress function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/).  You want [`is_tag()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tag).

Comment: you mean I need to use like
<?php if (!is_tag('121')) { ?>

Comment: @ashuthinks: Assuming that's the logic you're after, yes.

Comment: no its not working :( basically I want to hide HEADER if my category name is DEMO i.e tag_ID = 121

Comment: @ashuthinks: What's wrong with `is_category('DEMO')` ?

Comment: perfect thanks alot :) i thought should have to work with tag_ID